# Why cannot I print $form in my template file?

Tags: forms, theming

I have a "video" content type. I want to customize the template file for edit form,
page--node--add--video.tpl.php, but when I render (or print) `$form`, it returns `NULL`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no `$form` variable available in page.tpl.php (see the [docs](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21page.tpl.php/7) for a full list of available vars).

If you're trying to output the page content it's done like so:

```
<?php echo render($page['content']); ?>
```